# Home Screen or Unlock Screen or a AppWidget?

Tags: android

I am having some doubts on what the most efficient or logical way to implement the following within Android :

- I have a service checking for incoming UDP packets
- when a packet is received the user is alerted by showing a radial menu or a lock-screen, with several actions/icons to select. Something like the lock-screen in JB. The idea of a lock-screen seems fitting so that the actions cannot be activated incidentally (for example in your pants or jacket) but you actually need a more complex action to select.

So know my question would be, what is the most fitting solution ?

- A custom lock screen ?
- Or a lock-screen widget, even though I noticed it does not seem to offer a viable solution because my widget would not be shown as the first screen when entering the lock screen (or at least not during my tests on a SG3, which keeps showing time and lockscreen-message as the first screen).
- Or a custom Home Screen ?

Actually another couple of contstraints and questions are :

- when my service receives a UDP package it should also light up the screen and play a sound, is this even possible if we use the standard lock screens ?
- if we use a AppWidget in Lock screen implementation would it be possible to do the above and also let my Service update the widget ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not develop a DashClock Extension ?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock

Comment: well DashClock is actually a LockScreen AppWidget. I thought I could not set it as the primary lock screen widget but after some reading from the DashClock FAQ I found out "You can make this the primary lock screen widget, replacing the default clock, by first touching-and-holding it and then dragging it horizontally to the very rightmost position. "
This is working. Still I'd prefer developing our own simply because its for a customer and this would be another extra dependancy.